# Combine two gremlin queries with individual start steps into one

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have two gremlin queries, both with individual start steps. I have no control over their inner structure (they are passed to me as method arguments). My task is to combine them into a single traversal. So basically I need to implement this:

```java
public GraphTraversal<*,*> createUnion(
    GraphTraversal<*, *> t1, 
    GraphTraversal<*,*> t2
){
   // how?
}
```

We have to assume that:

- Both `t1` and `t2` have individual start steps (`.V()` / `.E()`)
- If `t1` starts with `.V()`, `t2` may start with `E()` or vice versa.

I tried the gremlin `union` step (which does accept sub-traversals), but the following (while syntactically valid) doesn't work:

```java
t1.union(
    __.identity(),
   t2
)
```

... because `union` steps in gremlin will always be evaluated **per input element** of t1. Clearly that's not what we want here.

I also tried the `inject(...)` step:

```
t1.inject(t2.toList().toArray(new Object[0]))
```

There are two issues with this:

1. `t2` is eagerly evaluated during the construction of the query
2. Any labels, side effects etc. which are defined in `t2` will not be available in the resulting traversal.

Are there any better ways to do this? Ideally a way that preserves the labels in `t1` and `t2` and preserves lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've often seen cases for `union()` to be a start step, but it hasn't been implemented as such yet. You can workaround this by using `inject()` and a throwaway traverser:

```
gremlin> t1 = __.V().has('person','name','josh');[]
gremlin> t2 = __.V().has('person','name','peter');[]
gremlin> g.inject(0).union(t1, t2)
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
```

The dummy or "0" is just used to start the traversal and then is ignored at the `union()` since the child traversals start with mid-traversal `V()`.

Take care to make sure that your traversal that uses this pattern will actually optimize the execution. An `explain()`/`profile()` should hint you into the underlying behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. `inject()` could have an override which accepts a traversal; this overload basically would have the same semantics as before, but pulls the elements lazily from the iterator. Ideally, labels and side effects from the injected traversal would carry over to the main one. Or let `inject()` have a lambda argument which is called when the traversal is actually executed instead of demanding the values outright (that would already help my case a lot as the secondary traversal wouldn't need to be fully executed before the root traversal even starts).